# I need Jquery script to run before Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys/gals I wrote a simple version of what I am trying to get working. Basically, I am trying to load html with jquery then gain access to the class/id's in Javascript. I am hoping for a little bit of help with it.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="HTMLHere"></div>

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("run me before ./javascript.js");
        $('#HTMLHere').load("amazing.html");
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
```

This does work. I don't have an issue with it running correctly it just runs out of order. I use amazing.html on quite a few pages and I am just trying to ease the maintenance a little. I do know I can do this with PHP but I would rather work with Jquery and Javascript.

Comment: Your jquery callback is executed only after the document is ready. The js file will be loaded before the entire document is ready.
This link might be useful. https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/loading-javascript/

Comment: we would need to see how you run the stuff in the javascript file

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies. Yeah I understand its ran after the document is ready. I am trying to get it to run before the ./javascript.js file. The javascript file needs to know of the 'amazing.html' to access the divs/form/button values.